# Problem related to divisors

Tags: integers, gcd-and-lcm

Here is the problem I am currently working on:

> Suppose $\frac{a}{b}$ is a rational zero of the equation $$ a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}x+a_n = 0,$$

where $a$ and $b$ are *relatively prime* integers and $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ are arbitrary integers. Show that $a$ is a divisor of $a_n$ and that $b$ is a divisor of $a_0$.

I have no idea how to even approach this proof. What I do know is that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers. In other words, their greatest common divisor is $1$ (so here we have *gcd*$(a,b) = 1$).

**EDIT**:

Originally, the textbook begins the question as

> Suppose that a/b  is a rational zero of the equation...

I just put it here just to follow the format of the textbook. I believe I'm suppose to split the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$ as  $$a * \frac{1}{b},$$

since the problem asks to show that $a$ is a divisor of $a_n$ and that $b$ is a divisor of $a_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{a}{b}$ is a solution to the equation, we have:
$$a_0\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n+a_1\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{n-1}+...+a_{n-1}\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+a_n=0\\a_0(a)^n+a_1(a)^{n-1}b+...+a_{n-1}(a)b^{n-1}+a_nb^n=0$$
The last step results from multiplying both sides of the equation by $b^n$, which must be nonzero. Now factor out an $a$ from everything except the $a_n$ term, and move $a_nb^n$ to the other side. Use the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=1$ to show that $a$ must divide $a_n$.

Comment: Okay Dave this should be enough to get me started. Anatoly's answer is also similar to yours as well.

Comment: I believe the equation is multiplied by $b^n$, not $b$.

Comment: You're right, that was a typo. The equation was multiplied by $b^n $, I just forgot to write that. Will fix.

Comment: No problem Dave.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $x $ with $\frac {a}{b} $ in the equation and multiplying both sides  to $b^n $   you have

$$ a_0a^n+a_1a^{n-1} b+...+a_{n-1}a b^{n-1}+a_n b^n= 0$$

In this equation,  all terms in the LHS except the last one contain the factor $a $, so $a_n $ must be divisibile by $a $. Similarly, all terms  except the first one contain the factor $b $, so $a_0$ must be divisibile by $b $.

Comment: Ahhh now I see it. And when you multiplied both sides by $b$, we know it's non-zero correct?

Comment: Yes, we know that it is non-zero.

Comment: Okay just double checking. This should be enough to get me started.